# Automatically insert in a SQL table after regular intervals

Tags: sql, xampp

I need to take all rows from **table1** and copy it to **table2** at midnight each day. Just like a backup.

*What could a possible way out?*

> I am using MySQL and Xampp server with PHP

Comment: You have to set cronjob

Answer (score 1):

You could use a cronjob if you're using linux or the scheduler if you're using windows.

Answer (score 1):

1. Expand the SQL Server Agent node and right click the Jobs node in
   SQL
2. Server Agent and select 'New Job' In the 'New Job' window enter the 
   name of the job and a description on the 'General' tab.
3. Select    'Steps' on the left hand side of the window and click
   'New' at the    bottom.
4. In the 'Steps' window enter a step name and select the    database
   you want the query to run against. Paste in the T-SQL    command you
   want to run into the Command window and click 'OK'.
5. Click    on the 'Schedule' menu on the left of the New Job window
   and enter    the schedule information (e.g. daily and a time). Click
   'OK' - and    that should be it.

**Let me know if it helps**